# Run function when header is include c++

Tags: c++, trigonometry

I am building a quick trigonometry function approximation in a single header file.

```
#ifndef COOL_MATH_H
#define COOL_MATH_H

#include <cmath>
const float PI = std::acos(-1);
namespace trigonometry
{
    namespace
    {
        float _cos[180];
    }

    void init()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 90; i++)
        {
            _cos[i] = cosf(float(i) * PI/180.0f);
        }
    }

    float cos(float deg)
    {
        int nearest = int(abs(deg) + 0.5) % 90;
        return _cos[nearest];
    }

    float sin(float deg)
    {
        return cos(90.0f - deg);
    }
}

#endif
```

Correct me if I am wrong, but this approximation is theoretically faster than the built-in trig function?

The main question is:
How can I run the function `trigonometry::init()` if the header file is included (i.e. only once)? I want to store the values of `_cos[180]` only once.

Comment: I also want to add linear interpolation to get better approximation, but I am afraid that having that much complexity will reduce the original goal of speed.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 yes

Comment: perhaps some workaround to compare them, like ```std::sinf(deg * pi/180.0f)```

Comment: I think you are confusing things, maybe misunderstanding the steps of building in C++. Trying to get things "run when headers are included" means you are not aware of the fundamentally different times when those things happen. All running happens substantially later than including. Including happens before the existence of an executable binary, running happens afterwards.

Comment: Your approximation is only good in the `[-89.5,89.5)` range. (Note, in particular, that `trigonometry::cos(90)` will not return the correct value.) You define `_cos` in the header, so every source file that includes it will have its own definition (which only avoids ODR violations because it is in an annonymous namespace). An you only access about half of the 180 elements you've allocated for `_cos`.

Comment: @Yunnosch I might have made myself unclear. I want to run the init() once if the header file is included. Something similar to python ```if __name__ != "main".```

Comment: OK, "run once, if a certain header is included" I can live with. It is relevantly different from "when". Sorry to nitpick. I recommend [edit] the question to avoid "when". Just in case others are as nitpicky as I am an get sidetracked from actually trying to help you.

Comment: Edited. @1201ProgramAlarm That's true. I could do something to convert ```trigonometry::cos(90)``` to ```trigonometry::cos(0)```.

Comment: `int(abs(deg) + 0.5) % 90;` The modulo operator implies an integer division which is nearly as slow as original `cosf` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I run the function trigonometry::init() when the header file is included (i.e. only once)?

```
#ifndef COOL_MATH_H
#define COOL_MATH_H

#include <cmath>
#include <array>

const float PI = std::acos(-1);
namespace trigonometry
{
    namespace
    {
        std::array<float, 180> init()
        {
            std::array<float, 180> cos;
            for (int i = 0; i < 90; i++)
            {
                cos[i] = cosf(float(i) * PI/180.0f);
            }
            return cos;
        }
        std::array<float, 180> _cos = init();
    }

    float cos(float deg)
    {
        int nearest = int(abs(deg) + 0.5) % 90;
        return _cos[nearest];
    }

    float sin(float deg)
    {
        return cos(90.0f - deg);
    }
}

#endif
```

Notice each translation unit including your cool_math.h will have own arrays `float _cos[180]` and weak functions. To have the unique `float _cos[180]` shared between all translation units you need to move the array and the functions definitions to cool_math.cc, or declare them as static members of some class and define `float _cos[180]` in cool_math.cc.

Comment: This is great. I probably should make a .cpp file to store the array